# Game design is scaled when exporting to iOS/Android from unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, scaling

I am new to unity and trying to build a simple game. When I work on unity Editor it seems to work fine.

Say in unity I am checking with dimension 1334x750:
[image]

And in phone it looks different - iphone7 - 750*1334

[image]

As you see, the text on top basket, the pink ball placement and other balls alignment all are different

Comment: Did you check that resolution on unity?

Comment: Hey BugFinder, I have checked device and editor both are same

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming everything here is under the Canvas GameObject.
In the Canvas Scaler Component of the Canvas select Scale with screen size.

If everything is not under Canvas the issue might be that the barrels are in world space whereas the letters are in Screen Space and hence they vary at different points.

You can use WorldtoScreenPoint() to set the position of the points

Comment: Hey Wahib, yea all the game object are under canvas scaler and you can see the screenshot I set it too scale with screen size